# Entering username password into popup with C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to automate the login into a website to pull some info from it.  I have a webbrowser control on my form which is hidden.  I set the webbrowser to the url I want and it then shows a certificate message and asks for the username and password with a username/password popup.  Is it possible to automate the process of inputting the username and password?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the username and password in the URL:

```
https://user:pass@example.com
```

This will work for [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Comment: there is a holo tickbox next to answers for you to select.